# rectangle function using a string

Tags: python, function

I've just started python and am stuck on this assignment where i need to create a function that does the following:

```
rectangle("ab", 3)

#output:

aba
bab
aba
```

where 3 is the length and height of the 'rectangle' and "ab" is the string used to draw the rectangle. It should be able to work with any string.

another example would be this :

```
rectangle("aybabtu", 5)

#output:

aybab
tuayb
abtua
ybabt
uayba
```

I'd would like to see the model answer to better understand the steps needed to create functions like this in the future, but that is only possible after completing the assignment. Thanks in advance!
Edit: Sorry for not posting my own code, i was kind of self concious and frustrated and scrapped it all, and its my first time asking a question. I will not repeat this mistake again

Comment: Could you post the code you attempted?

Comment: Please only post once you've tried something, no matter how simple/broken. For starters think about how many lines of text you need and how many letters each line has. Then manipulate your strings to reflect that.

Comment: what did you try? Where is your code?

Comment: I would first create one long string with all text and later split it into shorter lines. But first it need to calculate how many times to repeate input text to create this long string - it can be longer then needed in rectangle because later I will be splited to correct size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I would create long string with repeated text and later I would split it to lines.

I need to calculate how many times repeate text in rectangle - and it has to be rounded up, not rounded down. Then I can use it to create long string - it can be even longer because later I will slice it and it will skip last chars.

After creating long string I can use `for`-loop to slice it and print only single line.

You may also add line to list and later join lines with `'\n'` to return string instead of display it.

```
import math

def rectangle(txt, size):
    rect_len = size * size
    print('> rect_len:', rect_len)

    txt_len = len(txt)
    print('> txt_len :', txt_len)

    # round up to next int
    repeate = math.ceil(rect_len/txt_len)
    #repeate = int(rect_len/txt_len) + 1
    print('> repeate :', repeate)
    
    long_txt = txt*repeate
    print('> long_txt:', long_txt)
    
    for x in range(size):
        print(long_txt[:size])
        long_txt = long_txt[size:]

# --- main ---

print('---')    
rectangle("ab", 3)

print('---')    
rectangle("aybabtu", 5)
```

Result:

```
> rect_len: 9
> txt_len : 2
> repeate : 5
> long_txt: ababababab
aba
bab
aba
---
> rect_len: 25
> txt_len : 7
> repeate : 4
> long_txt: aybabtuaybabtuaybabtuaybabtu
aybab
tuayb
abtua
ybabt
uayba
```

Comment: Thank you Furas, your solution worked. I can post the 'model answer' if required, but the site which i'm doing the assignments on is currently down. Also, sorry for not posting my code, noobie mistake.